# celery periodic task data available for the celery workers

Tags: python, django, celery, periodic-task

I am getting data by periodic task using celery beat. this I have to share remaining workers. I am new to celery, how can I achieve? please give me a brief.
thank you in advance.

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'webapp.tasks.scraper_example',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=5),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}


@app.task
def scraper_example(a, b):
    out_response = requests.post(url=someurl,headers={"Content- 
                                 Type":"application/json",})
    result = out_response
```

Comment: Show what you have working now?

Comment: I want to make that result data as global data for all celery workers.

Comment: Im not really sure What you mean by share your workers? But anyhow, the worker uses what ever data you tell it to use in the task. So if you have data that needs to be shared from one task to another, then you need to save it in some form and fetch it again at the start of the other task. Does that make sense?

Comment: actually, it is not happening. I am using djcelery on windows. in the tasks.py I gave global variable and updated global value with the result in the periodic task. I tried to access that in other task but does not work

Comment: That wont work. If you want to use that variable, you will have to store it in some storage means like a DB or cache and then retrieve it again from your other task.

Comment: thank you, as you said I am gone through the Memcached for python. how to start Memcached. can you please explain me?

Comment: Use this link https://medium.com/@netfluff/memcached-for-django-ecedcb74a06d to setup memcached. It was helpful to me. I would also appreciate a vote if my answers were helpful. Thanks!